# WPF MVVM-Light adding an image to a listview item when selecting

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

I have a ListView that I want to be able to add a 'Delete' button to, with a command attached to it, when I select an item.  I can't find anything about this on stack which is quite surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by applying a style to the `ListViewItem` in the `ListView.Resources`. In the `Style`, you set the `ContentTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` with only a `TextBlock`. Then you give the `Style` a `Trigger` that is tied to the `IsSelected` property. In the `Trigger` you'll set the `ContentTemplate` to a new `DataTemplate` with a `TextBlock` and a `Button`. The `Command` property of the `Button`  is bound to the ViewModel using the `RelativeSource` binding and the `CommandParameter` is bound to the item so that it gets passed along as a parameter to your DeleteCommand.

**XAML**

```
<ListView Margin="3"
          MinWidth="200"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"
                                   Margin="3" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"
                                               Margin="3" />
                                    <Button Content="Delete"
                                            Margin="3"
                                            Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ICommand _DeleteCommand;
public ICommand DeleteCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_DeleteCommand == null)
        {
            _DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand<ExampleModel>(param => DeleteItem(param));
        }

        return _DeleteCommand;
    }
}

private void DeleteItem(ExampleModel item)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.SomeProperty);
}
```

I just have the Delete method showing the value in a MessageBox for demo purposes. You should be able to modify the DataTemplate and Delete method to meet your needs.